# Unhandled exception when printing MinValue MaxValue float to console

Tags: c#, input, formatting

When I printed byte Min and MaxValue to console it produces those values, when I tried the same with float however it came back with an unhandled exception,
   [link to image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jFod.png) When I build there comes no errors, yet when I run it, it comes back with this, is it a computer limitation or what?

```
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", byte.MinValue, byte.MaxValue);
        Console.WriteLine("{0) {1}", float.MinValue, float.MaxValue);
```

Comment: It's much preferred that you include any code or images directly in your question. And any code, should be in your question as text, not an image of your code (so people can copy and paste into their own environment to replicate your issue).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo in your string; there is a right parens ) next to the 0 instead of a bracket }.

Answer (score 2):

A way to avoid this problem in the future is to use the newer string interpolation syntax. Using this syntax, if you made the equivalent typo the compiler would catch it as a syntax error.

Example:

```
    Console.WriteLine($"{byte.MinValue} {byte.MaxValue}");
    Console.WriteLine($"{float.MinValue} {float.MaxValue}");

    Console.WriteLine($"{float.MinValue) {float.MaxValue}"); // Causes a syntax error
```